# Считывание чисел до Enter

Tags: java, scanner

Каким образом можно реализовать считывание чисел одной строкой через пробел до нажатия Enter? Например, чтобы каждое число добавлялось в ArrayList.

Comment: Брать всю строку, разделять её на отдельные числа по пробелу.

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос, [`Scanner::nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) как раз этим и занимается, в том смысле, что числа будут считываться до нажатия Enter

Answer (score 1):

Можно разбить строку на подстроки с числами, затем парсим в int ну или в другой тип

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String str = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(str);

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" "); // шаблон "пробел"
        String[] strings = pattern.split(str); // сепарируем по шаблону pattern
        List list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (String s : strings) {
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
        }


        for (Object i : list) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался